# .on() bindings not working after trigger('create')

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

In a JQM (1.3.0) app that I'm building, I bind all my submit buttons to a click event using "on" with the intent that all submit buttons now and in the future will have this event bound. I'm doing these bindings in the $(document).ready() because I figure it only needs to be called once...ever.

I update a JQM [panel](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/panels/index.html) with some content and call .trigger('create') on that content. What *should* happen is that the newly created submit button should trigger the bound click event when clicked, but it doesn't.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C2y7P/) demonstrating what I'm trying to achieve. In the demo, the message box should display "Clicked" whenever you click a submit button...unfortunately, it only happens with the first element.

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e){
        $('#msg').append('<div>Clicked</div>');
        $('#panel').html('<input type="submit" value="New Button">').trigger('create');
    });
});
```

Am I using .on() incorrectly here? I guess I could stuff all my bindings into a function, and then call that function whenever .trigger('create') is called...but that seems inefficient.

Comment: That's not how .on works

Comment: You would normally bind to a (common by selector) parent, in this case maybe a `form.class`. `$.live` bound to `document` I believe, which *is* inefficient. But the problem is nothing is *monitoring* clicks and delegating if certain *selector-designated* elements bubble (or capture?).

Comment: I figured :(, the docs say that on replaces live though. How would I bind "for the future"?

Comment: To a parent seen on load. If they're always in a `form` inserted on page load? Or `#content`? Something, it just should not be dramatically *top* like `document` or `body` or *every* click could be assessed for your `submit` selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to bind events using the [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method. One is using event delegation which works binding the event to a *higher* level element (all the way up to the `document` if necessary, but the *closer* the better) and then when an event bubbles up it listens to it and if it matched the passed in selector it fires. The second way to use `.on` is to bind it directly to the element without using delegation.

You are using the second version of `.on` way, but what you want is to use the first (delegation version).

For example instead of your current code you would  do something like the following

```
$(function(){
    $('#someParentElement').on('click','input[type="submit"]', function(e){
        $('#msg').append('<div>Clicked</div>');
        $('#panel').html('<input type="submit" value="New Button">').trigger('create');
    });
});
```

Comment: That's what I meant by *lower*

Comment: @JaredFarrish Well I originally used the word "lower" to contrast it with "higher".

Comment: Thanks, I dropped this into the fiddle and it worked. In my app I'll need to move it to the 'pageinit' to ensure that inputs created in *new* forms when the entire page is recreated are bound as well. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

You need

```
$('#someParentElement').on('click', 'input[type="submit"]', function(e){
   //handler
});
```

The way you had it was the equivalent of the old

```
$('input[type="submit"]').bind('click', function(e){
   //handler
});
```

Comment: I would *not* use `document`. That *is* inefficient.

Comment: oops - I didn't notice there was a container specified in the question